# Azure SDK not importing

Tags: java, azure

I downloaded the Azure SDK and added it as a library to my Netbeans project. However, the imports are still not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly you didn't add it the right way.  But unless you are more specific about what you did and how you did it, we can only guess as to what you did / are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a Java library is depended on some dependent libraries which you also download. My suggestion is that you can try to follow the NetBeans quick start document for Maven to install the Azure SDK library & its dependencies via Maven.

The maven repository of Azure SDK is at [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure/1.0.0), you just add the maven dependency content below within the xml element `dependencies` to the `pom.xml` file for your project on NetBeans.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, maven will help downloading & installing Azure SDK jar file & all dependencies when you save the maven `pom.xml` file.

Hope it helps.